# How do I allow unit stacking?

Tags: civilization-5

I am browsing Steam Community Mods and I can't find a mod that does this.

Comment: Close voters: I am thinking that this question (which sounds like a mod recommendation question) is actually *on-topic*, as per this meta post: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and Note that mod recommendation questions are *not* off-topic per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the ['Legions' mod](http://kael.civfanatics.net/Legions/index.shtml) - a mod for stacked unit combat for Civilization V. It's very old, though.

> This mod makes the following changes to Civilization V:
>
> - Removes the 1UPT (one unit per tile) limit.
> - Legions mod is completely modular and can be run concurrently with other mods.
> - Attack I promotion- +15% when attacking.
> - Attack II promotion- +15% when attacking.
> - Attack III promotion- +15% when attacking.
> - City Defense promotion- +25% when defending a city.
> - Defense I promotion- +15% when defending.
> - Defense II promotion- +15% when defending.
> - Defense III promotion- +15% when defending.
> - Shock promotions now give a standard +10% to combat instead of +20% on open terrain.
> - Unit maintenance is reduced by 25%.
> - Units in cities no longer get additional hit points, to adjust for the ability to stack defenders in cities.
>
> This mod doesn't add any new UI to help manage the ability to stack
>   units. So unit's still need to be moved individually, and there is no
>   easy way to look at the statistics of stacked units.

The UI doesn't compensate for stacked units - So it probably isn't ideal if you a lot of units (20+). However, it's very good for moving smaller amounts together (Less than 10?).

Comment: Can you provide some information about this mod, please?  Rather than having to click the link to learn about it.